# Probability to guess the right coin without tossing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, bayesian

I am looking at question 3b [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417665/hypothesis-test-between-two-coins):

Alice has two coins.  The probability of Heads for the first coin is $1/4$, and the probability of Heads for the second is $3/4$.  Other than this difference, the coins are indistinguishable.  Alice chooses one of the coins at random and sends it to Bob.  The random selection used by Alice to pick the coin to send to Bob is such that the first coin has a probability p of being selected.  For this part, assume that $p=3/4$.

Suppose instead that Bob tries to guess which coin he received without tossing it. He still guesses the coin in order to minimize the probability of error. What is the probability that Bob will guess the coin correctly under this scenario?

Isn't the answer just inherently $1/2$, as the coins are indistinguishable and there is no hint given howsoever?

Comment: Yes, it does!  Thank you!